# how to call RESTful web service in phonegap application?

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am writing a program to call some RESTful web services using jquery $ajax() function. the problem is that i am getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. Should I add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to all responses? and is it the best way to call RESTful web services in PhoneGap applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config.xml,

```
 <access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at  in the config.xml file of the app?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

Comment: You mean using `<access>` tag to white list the domain?

Comment: Yes, sorry the tag I typed got escaped out. :(